# Help - Cannot delete own answers

Tags: support, site-attributes

Hi,

I may be asking this in the wrong place (and if I am, please excuse me and move it to the appropriate place), but I am having some trouble with the gaming site, namely: I cannot seem to delete my own posts. All I have on my answers is: "link|edit|flag", but no "delete" link. Has there been a change in the way the site works? Does the site not recognize me as the poster of my answer?

Thank you.

Comment: Which question are you referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug that has been fixed now, see [this meta post for more information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89083/unable-to-delete-own-answers-the-delete-link-is-gone)